# Beginner woes about Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I am considering using selenium to interface with a program I created, which stores my User Id and password to all the sites I log in: the program then will put those two elements into the site to create an automatic log in.
I explored the Internet documentation and I am not clear on its capabilities.
First question: since all sites use different identifiers for those fields (“User ID, password”, “Login Id, Password”, “Card No., password”, etc.) is there a generic identifier capability for those fields or they have to be precisely addressed?
Second question: not clear either if I can use my stored cookies to accomplish that.
Unfortunately Amazon does not allow you anymore to see the details of the books on the subject and I am having problems selecting a good one on to buy.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no universal identifier for login/password fields on all websites. You have to manually specify some identifier for every page. Some may be same, but others will be different.

2) Selenium can find login field, input your credentials and then submit it - you are logged in. I don't think cookies could help you.

Edit: If you are thinking about making a pure login-only selenium app, I do not think it is a good idea. I guess it will not help you much and anytime the app can stop working because of website rework/new design.

Comment: thank you for the heads up! Anything else that will do the job or I will be just drowning in deep waters?